# Authorize.net seal and JS in footer

Tags: wordpress, javascript, authorize.net

So, utilizing Authorize.net, the verification seal code has a JS call in it.  However, when trying to save the online event registration page, CiviCRM complains that there may be a JS attack in progress.  Pulling the script bits out removes the error and the link still says it's verified.  The code is typical JS light, but seems very benign in the same way.  Anyone else experiencing such an issue?

Here's the JS call, with the potentially confidential bits mixed up:
`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">var ANS_customer_id="redacted";</script><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//verify.authorize.net/anetseal/seal.js" ></script>`

Wordpress:  4.5.2
CiviCRM:  4.7.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you trying to add the script -- in the "Footer" editor window on the Event details page?

If so, you probably need to add it in the Wordpress side (e.g. as an HTML/Text widget) rather than the CiviCRM editor to avoid these security notices. If you only want to have the widget show on CiviCRM pages, or SSL pages, etc. you may find [this Q&A on the Wordpress StackExchange site helpful](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76959/how-to-add-a-specific-widget-to-only-1-page) (more than one of the answers may be useful).

Comment: Yes, in the footer, and in the Thank You footer also.

Comment: Not to be a jerk, but ... I only want it showing up when there's money involved.

Comment: My understanding is that JS isn't allowed in the footers, but you could tackle this from the Wordpress side as I indicated. I've edited the answer to link to a Q&A that may help you find a way to designate the widget to show only on certain pages.

Comment: Marking this Answered, and hoping that a better option becomes available.  Too much administration being introduced this way.